# How to ignore Parent's event handler in order to use Child event handler (for DragEvent) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, drag

I am having a problem in using the `DragEventHandler`. 
The scenario is that: A parent element which has its own `DragEventHandler`s (in this case Grid) contains child element (Panel) which also has its own `DragEventHandler`s.

So when an item is dragged over the child element, the event handlers of the parent elt is used instead of the child. I 've child to use `child.PreviewDragEnter`.. instead of `DragEnter` but it does not work.

Strange enough, for `MouseEvent` like mouseEnter or mouseLeave handlers of both Parent and child work.

Can anyone help me with that. How can the drageventhandler of the Child elt be used instead.

Thank you very much.

Comment: First of all, what language are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say too much without more details of the language and library you are using.. But one common trick I've seen is to make sure you instantiate the bindings of the child elements BEFORE the parent elements if you want them to be separate from the parent...

Comment: HI, Thanks for your response. 
I am using C#.
For the child element, I extend the Panel class and use this.DragEnter, this.DragLeave...  to assign an event handler to it. 

XAML will be: <Grid> <ExtendedPanel> ... </ExtendedPanel></Grid>. The compiler will initiate the Parent first. How do I instantiate the bindings of the child before the element?